# Python: Returning 0 in min(list) with no min of 0

Tags: python, int, min

I'm creating a command that will take a partial or whole name match of a process and kill its lowest pid - and thus the rest of the processes spawned from it.  My code returns a min(list_of_process_ids) of 0, of which there is no min of 0.  Please enlighten me as to why this is happening. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Kill proceses by partial name matching"""

import os, sys

def usage():
    return ("pskill.py process_name")

def pids(proc):
    """ Find the processes"""
    procs = []
    procs = os.system("ps -ef|grep -i " + proc + "|grep -v grep|grep -v pfind|awk '{print $2}'")
    procs = [int(x) for x in str(procs)]
    return procs

def kill(procs):
    ppid = min(procs)
    os.system("kill " + str(ppid))
    return ("Processes Killed...")

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print (usage())
    else:
        proc = sys.argv[1]
        pids(proc)
        kill(pids(proc))

main()
```

Comment: What visible behavior did you observe that made you think "My code returns a min(list_of_process_ids) of 0, of which there is no min of 0"? Your code doesn't print `procs` or `ppid`.

Comment: `os.system` doesn't return stdout. It returns an exit status.

Comment: you may find `pgrep`/`pkill` to be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't grabbing the `stdout`, so you aren't actually getting anything other that the exist status of the command. Which you can be glad is 0 :-)
Try using [the subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html). Specifically with the stdout option of piping the result to your python console...

Comment: I replaced os.system with subprocess.check_output and it worked to give me output I can manage from there.

Comment: Glad I helped :-)